# Access attribute specified by XPath with xml_grep

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, grep

How can I access the value of an attribute specified via XPath with `xml_grep`?

I've tried:

```
# svn info http://unladen-swallow.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ --xml > x
# cat x
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<info>
<entry
   kind="dir"
   path="trunk"
   revision="1171">
<url>http://unladen-swallow.googlecode.com/svn/trunk</url>
<repository>
<root>http://unladen-swallow.googlecode.com/svn</root>
<uuid>05521daa-c0b4-11dd-bb00-bd6ab96fe29a</uuid>
</repository>
<commit
   revision="1171">
<author>ebo@4geeks.de</author>
<date>2010-08-21T18:17:31.382601Z</date>
</commit>
</entry>
</info>



# xml_grep uuid x --text_only
05521daa-c0b4-11dd-bb00-bd6ab96fe29a
# xml_grep //info/entry/@path x --text_only # correct XPath syntax
error: unrecognized expression in handler: '//info/entry/@path' at /usr/bin/xml_grep line 198
# xml_grep //info/entry/[@path] x --text_only
# # no output
```

I've looked at the online help pages, but the only syntax that matches a property at all is far too verbose:

```
# xml_grep '*[@path]' x
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xml_grep version="0.7" date="Wed Aug 28 15:22:13 2013">
<file filename="x">
  <entry kind="dir" path="trunk" revision="1171">
    <url>http://unladen-swallow.googlecode.com/svn/trunk</url>
    <repository>
      <root>http://unladen-swallow.googlecode.com/svn</root>
      <uuid>05521daa-c0b4-11dd-bb00-bd6ab96fe29a</uuid>
    </repository>
    <commit revision="1171">
      <author>ebo@4geeks.de</author>
      <date>2010-08-21T18:17:31.382601Z</date>
    </commit>
  </entry>
</file>
</xml_grep>
#
```

What's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xml_grep` is a very simple tool that uses Perl's `XML::Twig` module. The allowed sytax for the *XPath-like* expressions is [documented there](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig#twig_handlers). It seems that it is impossible to extract the value of an attribute like this.

I suggest using the `xpath` program instead:

```
$ xpath x '//entry/@path'
Found 1 nodes:
-- NODE --
 path="trunk"
```

This program should come bundled with [`XML::Xpath`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aXPath).

---

If all else fails, just roll your own. My weapon of choice is `XML::LibXML`:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my ($file, $query) = @ARGV;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $file);
print $xml->findvalue($query), "\n";
```

Then `$ perl xpath-findvalue.pl x '//entry/@path'`. Output: `trunk`.

Comment: Should have, but did not.  Is it possible to use `xpath` to only send the value to `stdout`?

Comment: @SeanAllred Ok. If there is no tool that does what we want, we can write our own. This finally works. In the code I used XML::LibXML because it is my usual library, but it works just as well with one of the dozen other XML libs.